# Detect strings with numbers and letters

Tags: regex, python-3.x

How can I find strings in text with a mix of BOTH LETTERS AND NUMBERS using regex?  For example:

```
ca199220
b2ad
45e1
00D61000000ZPjx
```

The strings I am looking for are not always the same length, may start with either numbers of letters, and have numbers and letters dispersed in them.

To clarify, I would like to take a string

```
test = 'yay over here ca19922 i have some 00D61000000ZPjx'
re.sub(r'insert some regex', '', test)
#return test = 'yay over here i have some'
```

My solution was:

```
import re
import nltk
[re.sub(r'^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])\w+', '', w) for w in nltk.word_tokenize(test) if len(re.sub(r'^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])\w+', '', w))>0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex that matches only input with both numbers and letters is:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).+
```

This uses 2 look aheads, one for each required type of character.

Using look aheads makes adding more requirements easy; you can just add more of them as you need.

Comment: I would put a `\w` instead of . if you want to match only continuos words, although it is not clear from OP.